# How to get AsyncHttpResponseHandler response as a JSONObject?

Tags: java, android, rest

My Java Restful service login method returns a JSONObject (with name, username, and so on) in a ResponseBuilder entity. I'm trying to get it inside an AsyncHttpResponseHandler (using [loopj](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/)) in my Android app. The problem is: the onSuccess method expecting a byte[] response, not a JSONObject. How to get the JSONObject inside onSuccess method in order to use it's values (user data) on my app?

Here is my code:

My Restful API login method

```
public Response login(@Context HttpHeaders httpHeaders,
            @FormParam("username") String username,
            @FormParam("password") String password) {

        Authenticator authenticator = Authenticator.getInstance();
        String serviceKey = httpHeaders
                .getHeaderString(HTTPHeaderNames.SERVICE_KEY);

        try {
            // My login method returns an JSONObject with data of the logged user
            JSONObject obj = authenticator
                    .login(serviceKey, username, password);

            return getNoCacheResponseBuilder(Response.Status.OK).entity(obj)
                    .build();

        } catch (final LoginException ex) {
            return getNoCacheResponseBuilder(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED)
                    .entity(ex.getMessage()).build();
        }
    }
```

Login method on my app:

```
 private void loginTask(RequestParams params){
    AppRestClient.post("access/login", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] response) {             

            // Here I want to get the JSONObject, but response is
            // returning something like [B@653abba
            Log.d(TAG, response);

        }

       ...
  }
```

Should I transform byte[] into JSONObject (if yes, how can I do that?) or should I change my ResponseBuilder entity to return something different than a JSONObject?

I already tried to use the JsonHttpResponseHandler class but the response is empty.